# Ripple effect not work with Layout onClick

Tags: java, android

I used many time this Ripple effect but on this page, it does not work on Click to the image.

I tried this method also on this layout(cover), but still, it did not work. I use RecyclerView so I put the Adapter Code and the RecyclerView Item layout.

RecyclerViewItem_layout.xml:

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:elevation="0dp"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cover"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect_for_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_one"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white_to_black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxWidth="90dp"/>
</RelativeLayout> 
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

AdapterClass.java:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterCategory.viewH holder, int position) {
        holder.img.setImageResource(modelCategories.get(position).getImg());
                holder.cover.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    if (position==0){
                        Intent ig = new Intent(new Intent(getActivity(), OrderDailyGrocery.class));
                        ig.putExtra("sentMsg",Grocery);
                        startActivity(ig);
                    }else if (position == 1){
                        Intent ig = new Intent(new Intent(getActivity(), OrderDailyGrocery.class));
                        ig.putExtra("sentMsg",Fruits);
                        startActivity(ig);
                    }else if (position == 2){
                        Intent ig = new Intent(new Intent(getActivity(), PickupDrop.class));
                        startActivity(ig);
                    }else if (position==3){
                        Intent ig = new Intent(new Intent(getActivity(), OrderDailyGrocery.class));
                        ig.putExtra("sentMsg",Meat);
                        startActivity(ig);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelCategories.size();
    }

    public class viewH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
        RelativeLayout cover;
        public viewH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            cover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        }
    }
```

> Ripple_effect_for_image.xml

```
<ripple
android:color="#50CF1A87">
<item>
    <color android:color="#50AA2626" />
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: try this for your RelativeLayout  `android:background="?attr/selectedItemBackground"`

Comment: @Sniffer android:background="?attr/selectedItemBackground" is not available so I used this and still not work  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground".

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40924983/5978440)

Answer (score 0):

Use MaterialCardView instead of CardView. It has default property for set ripple effect. (#app:rippleColor)

Check this one:
https://material.io/components/cards/android#using-cards